# ubuntu server login doesn't appear when lid is open on a old MacBook Pro 201

Tags: server, 22.04, suspend, macbook-pro, lid

I've installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 on an old MacBook Pro 2010 i7 to use it as home server. Everything seams working properly, I'm able to connect to Mac via ssh but when I try to use it directly, login page doesn't appear when I open lid. Screen it's switched on, arrow is moving when I move mouse but nothing else appear. The only way to use it is reboot the system or via ssh.
Does somebody have some suggestion?
Many thanks in advance